# style only some items in a list

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to just style some items in an html list?

For example

[image]

Is there a way to put a border around just the last 2 items in the list?

Comment: Yes it's possible, what have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tried this:

```
:last-child,
:nth-last-child(2) {
  ruleset
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:nth-last-child()` pseudo selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo) to put a style around the last two list items (`li` elements) in a list.

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    your styles go here
}
```

Note that `:nth-last-child()` is *not* supported in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by using the `:not` selector:

```
div ul:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

This would select all items except for the first one, regardless of the number of items.

Additionally, if you are constructing a `for` loop in your HTML, you can add a class to all items in the forloop counter except for the first one.

Answer (score 2):

If the list is a known length, you can also use the nth-child pseudo class such as:

```
li:nth-child(n+2) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This will put a border around all but the first item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can also this for second child element

```
li:first-child + li  {
border: 1px
```

}

This to put border to third child element

```
    li:first-child + li + l1 {
border: 1px
```

}